# When updating from kernel 3.13 -> linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic the network was lost - how do I preserve it when updating the kernel

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

Happy New Year, hopefully.

Earlier today I tried to update my kernel from 3.13xx to 4.2 in the hope of better performance on my computer. But after a restart I had no network. When i did ifconfig ethx/wlanx up it gave an error message.
I had to remove the new kernel and reboot the old kernel to get the network back.

How do I keep the network drivers between kernels? Does not the dependencies hop along between kernels?

Perhaps a better question would be - what are the appropriate steps to install a kernel and keeping the drivers working between kernel-generations? If there is a manual I would read it, but I have not found Potters book of knowledge where all the magick Linux are collected in one large volume. In this case I would like to read the chapter *x.x.x.IV Kernel Update do and do not.*

Comment: How did you install the 4.2 kernel? Wired or wireless networking? What type of card? What driver?

Comment: Have you confirmed it is a driver issue specifically (rather than, for example, a change in the interface naming convention)? What was the error message?

Comment: What packages did you update?  There are "lts" kernel upgrade packages, but I did a successful update of my 14.04 to 4.2.3 with just the kernel package and the firmware package.  You need more than just the kernel package.

Comment: Hi I did apt-cache search linux-image   THEN 
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic   I will have to do another update to see the error message:) That solution came from another place on the internet. Perhaps from another thread on this site. Wireless update I cannot give you *new line*

Comment: WIRELESS 02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
ETHERNET 01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01) ______I only updated the kernel and no other packages because the network has worked when the kernels have been updated before within the 3.-branch of kernels ____when the kernels have been updated automatically they have always been the GENERIC

Comment: lspci -v | grep Network -A 20 ___gave the following on wireless and driver______02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device 0632
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
 Memory at b0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
 Expansion ROM at 9fc00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k

Comment: @fkraiem this perhaps notifies you.

Comment: Install `linux-image-generic-lts-wily`, this will 1) install `linux-image-extra-4.2.0-22-generic`, which may contain the driver for your wifi card, and 2) ensure you get all updates for the 4.2 series of kernels.

Answer (score 1):

@fkraiem
That solved the problem.

> Install linux-image-generic-lts-wily, this will 1) install
>   linux-image-extra-4.2.0-22-generic, which may contain the driver for
>   your wifi card, and 2) ensure you get all updates for the 4.2 series
>   of kernels. – fkraiem 3 hours ago